# VBA ComboBox Copy Fails Sporadically

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

I'm creating a form with 3 comboboxes that the user can fill out. When they click the "new row" button, the form should create a new line directly underneath the most recent line with 3 blank comboboxes.

THE ISSUE: Occasionally, when the user selects one of the boxes out of order (for example, they click combobox 2 before combobox1) and then they click the "new row" button, the second two boxes copy correctly but the first combobox does not get copied to the correct row. It always copies to the top left row of the table. 
(See visual)

Correct:

[image: Correct result]

Incorrect:

[image: Incorrect result]

Here is my code:

```
'Declare variables
Dim curIndirectRow As Integer

'Search for keyword in column B; search direction: top to bottom
'Set findTable to the coordinates of matching word
Set findTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("B:B").Find(What:="Indirect Damages", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)

'If the line immediately after the found word is blank (meaning it's the first row)
If Range(findTable.Address).Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
    'set variable to be the first row
    curIndirectRow = Range(findTable.Address).Row
    Else
    'set variable to be the last row in the table
    curIndirectRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range(findTable.Address).End(xlDown).Row
End If

'Add one blank row underneath your last row
Range("$B$" & curIndirectRow).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
'Copy the row above it into your newly inserted row(no buttons included)
Sheets("Main").Range("B" & CStr(findTable.Row) & ":F" & CStr(findTable.Row)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Main").Range("B" & CStr(curIndirectRow + 1) & ":F" & CStr(curIndirectRow + 1))
'Clear the values of the Approver cell
Sheets("Main").Range("$F$" & CStr(curIndirectRow + 1)).Value = ""

'Select the first box ("Type") and copy
Sheets("Main").Shapes.Range(Array("Combobox8")).Select
Selection.Copy
'Paste the first box into your new row's C column
Sheets("Main").Range("C" & CStr(curIndirectRow + 1)).PasteSpecial
'Populate the drop down list
Sheets("Main").Shapes("ComboBox" & CStr(Sheets("Main").Shapes.Count - 63)).OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = "=Lists!D2:D6"
'Set the default value to blank
Sheets("Main").OLEObjects("ComboBox" & CStr(Sheets("Main").Shapes.Count - 63)).Object.Value = ""
```

The code for the first box is repeated for the second and third boxes. Note that I subtract 63 from the count of the Shapes on the sheet because there are 63 other shapes (checkboxes, etc) that are not comboboxes.

Comment: Have you checked out the Top, Left, TopLeftCell properties of shapes?

Comment: Another approach - how about disabling combobox2 and 3 until an option has been chosen for combobox1?

Comment: @dwirony this is an interesting idea I could employ, but how would I make the others programatically disable once the new row has been created?